# The string is not a valid regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a folder with DNS .zone files.

I'm trying to return all files and the string that have an IP address that looks like `172.20.*`.

I use the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:\Root' | Select-String -Pattern '*172.20.*' | group | select name
```

but this returns:

> Select-String : The string *172.20.* is not a valid regular expression: parsing "*172.20.*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

I tried using the `-SimpleMatch` case in my `Select-String` without success. Enclosing the string in double quotes is also not working.

If I use actual text as my pattern, it works without a problem.

Where is my problem?

Comment: You cannot quantify the start of the pattern. `'*'`  is an invalid regex.

Comment: thanks for your comment what work around would i need to use to allow this @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: It all depends what you want to match and where. Maybe `'\b172\.20\b'` is all you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the error message says: `*172.20.*` is not a valid regular expression. It's a wildcard pattern, which can be used with the `-like` operator, but not with `Select-String`. `*` in a regular expression is a modifier that cannot stand by itself, it requires something that it applies to. The regular expression equivalent of a wildcard `*` (match zero or more characters) is `.*`. But since regular expressions (unlike wildcard patterns) are not anchored by default, you don't need to add them at the beginning and end of your pattern for the match to work.

Either change your expression to an actual regular expression:

```
... | Select-String -Pattern '172\.20\.' | ...
```

or modify your code to use wildcard matches instead of regular expression matches:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse  -Path 'C:\Root' | Where-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object { $_ -like '*172.20.*' }
} | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Using `-SimpleMatch` did not work with your approach, because `-Pattern '*172.20.*' -SimpleMatch` would be looking for a literal (sub)string `*172.20.*` (with the asterisks), which probably isn't present in your files. It would have worked had you removed the wildcards from the pattern:

```
... | Select-String -Pattern '172.20.' -SimpleMatch | ...
```