# Wildcard before and after search

Tags: python, wildcard

I'm working on a project that searches for filenames that match a string. The current working code appends an `*` to the end of the string and the code properly takes the string and matches it when there's a file extension and/or a number after, that works right.  I'm wanting it to ignore things before the initial string as well to check the interior of the file name. For example `File A File B.txt` will be found by a string search for `File A` "or `File B`

Working code:

```
redeemed = redeemed + "*"
results = [file for file in sounds if re.search(redeemed, file)]
```

Non-working code:

```
redeemed = "*" + redeemed + "*"
results = [file for file in sounds if re.search(redeemed, file)]
```

Returns error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-19' coro=<PubSub.__handle_message() done, defined at C:\Users\dmvh1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twitchAPI\pubsub.py:293> exception=error('nothing to repeat at position 0')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twitchAPI\pubsub.py", line 298, in __handle_message
    sub(uuid, msg_data)
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TwitchSounds\InProgress.py", line 34, in callback_redemptions
    results = [file for file in sounds if re.search(redeemed, file)]
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TwitchSounds\InProgress.py", line 34, in <listcomp>
    results = [file for file in sounds if re.search(redeemed, file)]
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 200, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 303, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_compile.py", line 788, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 955, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 444, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 669, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

We were concerned the code with *redeemed* would catch EVERYTHING, but instead it catches nothing. Any ideas on how to implement this search?

Comment: You start your regex with a `*` but it requires something in front of it, so your regex is invalid. Maybe you want `.*`? It's unclear what you're trying to wildcard. Do you just want a Path glob rather than a regex?

Comment: A regular expression pattern is not a globbing pattern. Use `.*` instead. Or probably `.*?` for the first one.

Comment: If you're searching for files, consider using `glob.glob` instead.

Comment: This is the same underlying problem described in [the string is not a valid regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406829/the-string-is-not-a-valid-regular-expression), even though that's not a Python-centric question.

Comment: BTW, the not-filesystem-specific equivalent to the `glob` module is `fnmatch`, which implements the syntax you're looking for.

Comment: Do not edit answers into questions. Do not edit information about which answers worked into questions. Show that an answer worked by clicking the checkmark next to it (which also changes how your question is shown on the main page to reflect that it's solved), or adding a comment _on the answer_ to that effect.

Comment: Check mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a plain text search, you don't need regex *or* glob:

```
results = [file for file in sounds if redeemed in file]
```

No `*` or `.*` needed

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `file` hasn't been a builtin since Python 2.

Comment: Ah, right you are; `file` is no longer a builtin, so it's fine to use as a general variable name. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the filename is handled as a String than don't bother with the `anyString+*`
Just search for whatever you want to find in the string

If my sources are correct the python `search()` will do the trick for you
"search() functions return a Match object if they find a match of a pattern in a string....search() matches anywhere in the string"

Like this

```
results = [file for file in sounds if re.search(redeemed, file)]
```

Comment: well then, the whole wildcard input was COMPLETELY unnecessary lol.  dont I feel stupid, its working great thanks